# Necessary and sufficient condition for almost sure convergence of a series of i.i.d. random variables.

Tags: probability-theory, expected-value

> Let $\{X_{n}\}_{n \geq 1}$ be a sequence of iid random variables with $\mathbb E[|X_1|^\alpha] < \infty$
> for some $\alpha > 0$. Derive a necessary and sufficient condition on $\alpha$ for almost sure convergence of the series $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}X_{n}\sin(2\pi nt)$ for all
> $t \in (0, 1)$.

I tried to prove that for any $\epsilon > 0$, the sequence of partial sums forms a Cauchy sequence in $L^\alpha$ space. But that didn't help.

Comment: Did you try Kolomogorov's Three series Theorem?

Comment: I tried taking c = 1 and random variable to be X_{n}sin2*pi*n*t. Couldn't get anywhere. @geetha290krm. All I could conclude was it has to be the case that E|X_{1}| < \infty. But nothing further.

Comment: any hint would be appreciated. @geetha290krm